# How to remove an element without id

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following code:

```
<%-- other tags --%>
<table>
  <tr width="100%">
    <td width="130" />
    <td id="BottomCell" width="100%" />
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td/>
    <td/>
  </tr>
</table>
<%-- other tags --%>
```

There may be more than one table on the page. I want the `td` before "BottomCell" to be removed (or hidden) when the page is loaded. How can I do this with javascript or css?

Thanks.

BTW, I'm developing a Sharepoint WebPart that will be put onto a page. The  is on that page, which i don't have control of directly. But the WebPart should remove this  as long as it shows up on the page.

Comment: We need more information. From which context are you wanting it to be removed? There are multiple ways of doing it.

Comment: Also, are you using jquery, prototype or any other js library?

Comment: if you remove the first `<td>`, your rows will have a different count of columns … that won't be valid html anymore without the `colspan` attribute

Comment: Highlight the markup with your cursor and press the Delete key

Comment: @knittl That is not true *at all*

Comment: @josh, well, how are the browsers supposed to render a table with a different number of columns in each row?

Comment: @knittl, you should try it. I just tried it and a table still renders.

Comment: @bob, well »still renders« in your browser, in your version, in that case. doesn't mean it renders everywhere

Comment: @knittl It's *supposed* to truncate the cells from the end of the row.  Imagine a table with 6 columns and only 5 of them require headings.  Instead of an empty cell for the column heading, there should be no cell (and no border) at all.

Comment: @knittl, my browser includes Opera, Safari, Chrome, Firefox, and IE 6-8 from IE Tester. That pretty much covers all the major browsers, so yes, it does render everywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wow, going back to basics after using a framework is hard work.

```
var element = document.getElementById('BottomCell').previousSibling;
var parent = element.parentNode;
parent.removeChild(element);
```

Comment: If it is, then you didn't learn the basics in the first place. ;)

Comment: No, it's just all the damn typing.

Comment: I applied your approach and it works perfectly. I use the code for window.onload event. It seems the tr is removed after the page has been rendered. So I see some jagged movements. Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: @bryan: just don't add your column to your code? what's the point in adding it anyway?

Comment: @knittl, I've explained why in the end of the question. Thanks.

Comment: @Bryan, well, since the title of this posting includes "without id", my approach tried to accomplish that without the use of an id, but since you used the id anyway, it begs the question why you wouldn't just use the id on the first cell and remove it that way. In any case, all id's on a page need to be unique, else you can't be sure which element you'll get if you use document.getElementById

Answer (score 4):

In jQuery:

```
$('#BottomCell').prev().detach();
```

Comment: Haven't tried JQuery, but I assume this should work. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

`tr > td` should do the trick.

Child and Sibling selectors

http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

Comment: Thanks. I may have more than one tr, and only in one of the tr I want to remove a td

Answer (score 1):

@diodeus if there are only 2 data cells that would be acceptable, however if you wish to remove the first data cell regardless of however many cells are located in that row, you can do something like

```
var el = document.getElementById('BottomCell');
el.removeChild(el.parentNode.firstChild);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, assuming you have only one table, then you could do something like this (in javascript):

```
var firstCell = document.getElementsByTagName('tr')[0].getElementsByTagName('td')[0];
firstCell.parentNode.removeChild(firstCell);
```

It would get the first cell of the first row in the entire DOM tree, and remove that cell.

Comment: though it's not necessary that it's the first tr in the document.

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery I would find the parent and use the `:first` selector probably